# How to plot combo line plot using different x-value intervals but same range?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

[Dataset sample for the monthly sales and semesterly sales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g4ju.jpg)

My data set :

```
     Monthly_Sales
Date    
28-02-2010  1057405
31-03-2010  1010665
30-04-2010  1028499
31-05-2010  1037282
30-06-2010  1068034
31-07-2010  1033689
31-08-2010  1042445
30-09-2010  984821
31-10-2010  965163
30-11-2010  1126963
31-12-2010  1283380
31-01-2011  909466
28-02-2011  1035174
31-03-2011  996424
30-04-2011  1006784
31-05-2011  1009156
30-06-2011  1054296
31-07-2011  1021828
31-08-2011  1047774
30-09-2011  981545
31-10-2011  1018118
30-11-2011  1167568
31-12-2011  1280347
31-01-2012  938302
29-02-2012  1067019
31-03-2012  1028931
30-04-2012  1049560
31-05-2012  1048702
30-06-2012  1069379
31-07-2012  1041719
31-08-2012  1052670
30-09-2012  1003586
31-10-2012  1024231
```

and 2nd:

```
    Semesterly_Sales
Date    
28-02-2010  1057405
31-08-2010  1036332
28-02-2011  1056477
31-08-2011  1022064
29-02-2012  1079750
31-08-2012  1048697
28-02-2013  1013908
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the graph function of pandas, you can easily stack different time periods.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
Date Monthly_Sales
28-02-2010  1057405
31-03-2010  1010665
30-04-2010  1028499
31-05-2010  1037282
30-06-2010  1068034
31-07-2010  1033689
31-08-2010  1042445
30-09-2010  984821
31-10-2010  965163
30-11-2010  1126963
31-12-2010  1283380
31-01-2011  909466
28-02-2011  1035174
31-03-2011  996424
30-04-2011  1006784
31-05-2011  1009156
30-06-2011  1054296
31-07-2011  1021828
31-08-2011  1047774
30-09-2011  981545
31-10-2011  1018118
30-11-2011  1167568
31-12-2011  1280347
31-01-2012  938302
29-02-2012  1067019
31-03-2012  1028931
30-04-2012  1049560
31-05-2012  1048702
30-06-2012  1069379
31-07-2012  1041719
31-08-2012  1052670
30-09-2012  1003586
31-10-2012  1024231
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

data2 = '''
Date Semesterly_Sales   
28-02-2010  1057405
31-08-2010  1036332
28-02-2011  1056477
31-08-2011  1022064
29-02-2012  1079750
31-08-2012  1048697
28-02-2013  1013908
'''
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data2), delim_whitespace=True)
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
df2.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

ax = df.plot(kind='line')
df2.plot(kind='line', ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: can you also tell if I have to do insights in this data how can i zoom or pan this plot or resize if possible?

Comment: It is difficult to zoom and pan in matplotlib graphs. you can change the size to the desired size by adding figsize=(width,height). If you want to zoom and pan, I recommend a library called plotly. Click here for [more information](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#line-charts-with-markers).